# Django: Not able to get bio field from table to be displayed on page

Tags: python, django, view, model

I developed a small test app with a profile page with user info and bio.
Everything is showing except the **bio** field, this is silly and driving loopy.
I tried so many combinations to no avail. Please see my code below: Someone please help.

Models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse
# Create your models here.

class TeacherProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio = models.TextField()

    def __str_from__(self):
        return self.user
```

Views.py

```
def teacher_profile(request,pk):
    teacher_profile = TeacherProfile.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'registration/teacher_profile.html', {
        'teacher_profile':teacher_profile
        })
```

html

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h1 class="page_heading">Teacher profile</h1>
            <strong>Welcome back:</strong> {{user.username}} |
            {{user.first_name}} {{user.last_name}} |
            {{user.email}} |
            <strong></strong>|
            <a href="{% url 'edit_teacher_profile_view_url' user.pk %}">edit profile</a><br> |
            <a href="{% url 'logout' %}">logout</a><br>
            <strong>About me:</strong> 
            {{user.bio}}
            <hr>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: please note that all other info is displayed on the html page  but the Bio field

Comment: Change `{{user.bio}}` to `{{ teacher_profile.bio }}`? Plus, aren't you just trying to send in one teacher profile to the template? You would use `get` instead of `all` and Instead of `user`, you would reference the `teacher_profile.user.whatever` perhaps.

Comment: Are you using Oracle? So, Oracle does not support collations for a `TextField`

Answer (score 0):

As explained by @Jarad in the comments above. The variable name available in the django-template would be `teacher_profile` as this is what is sent in context.

```
'teacher_profile':teacher_profile
```

Here, you can use:

```
{{ teacher_profile.bio }}
```

If you are wondering why `user.first_name` and `user.last_name` are working then. It is because, in the template, Django already pass the template variable {{ user }}. [refer related django-doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/default/#authentication-data-in-templates).